# Can I make a Flensing Slice the round after I make the Double Slice that qualifies for it?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e

So... this is mostly about the Dual Weapon Warrior archetype.  Double Slice is a two-diamond action that lets you strike twice.  Flensing Slice is a one-diamond action that lets you do bad things to the target as long as your last action was a double slice in which you attacked them twice and hit both times.  Now, by the narrative, it seems like the flensing strike was intended to occur in the same round as the double slice, but I don't see anything in the rules that would require that.  Am I missing something?  Is it possible to double slice in one round, and then (assuming that you don't perform any reactions or other actions in between) flensing slice as your first action of the following round?

Answer (score 3):

### No, the situation you propose isn't possible.

Flensing Slice says:

> When you hit with both attacks with Double Slice, you flense the target, making it bleed and creating a weak spot. The target takes 1d8 persistent bleed damage per weapon damage die of whichever of the weapons you used that has the most weapon damage dice (maximum 4d8 for a major striking weapon). The target becomes flat-footed, and its resistances to any physical damage types are reduced by 5; these two effects last until the beginning of your next turn.

The very first line of the feat description says **"when you hit"**. If you don't use it immediately after *in the same turn*, then it's not "when you hit" it's "6 seconds after you hit", which isn't how the feat is described to work.

Comment: Okay.  This is based on the reading of that line as having strong rules implications rather than being fluff.  Whether or not that's true generally depends on the system in question.  Do you know that Pathfinder 2 is one of the systems that uses the "all description is crunch description" writing form?

Comment: Do you have some reason to think it doesn't? As far as I can tell (and in my expert opinion), there is no text in any feats, spells, or other abilities that is "fluff text only". Instead, they all follow the general design of "describe how thing functions in a general sense, then describe mechanics of such". So far, I haven't seen any abilities that contain text which could be considered *obvious* fluff.

Comment: Sure... but my read had been that the first sentence is often/generally used as a description of what happens, which is then laid out in more specific crunch later.  So this line translates more or less directly to the requirements and effects part of the crunch.. which does *not* require that it all be the same turn.

Comment: @BaconyRevanant The text of [Dual Onslaught](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1955) mentions the target has "no room to escape your attack", but doesn't specify anything about the target being unable to move out of the way. I don't think it's the greatest example, but I think some extra evidence would be necessary to say that all "fluff text" is binding. That being said, I don't think your answer relies upon the "fluff text", since the "when you hit" condition is in the Requirements section of the action as well.

Comment: @ESCE yeah? ...but the actual requirements line is "Your last action was a Double Slice, and both attacks hit the target."  Thus my question - the requirements read as per the requirements line doesn't seem to prevent doing it the next turn, as long as you perform no other actions in between.

Comment: Feats have a requirements section which defines when they may be used. You don't reference the body of the feat for that.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the requirements, it seems that the action for the feat could be done with the first action of you next round, if the last action of the previous round was Double Slice. I know that that doesn't match the below description very well, and what I think is that probably the feat is missing the Press trait by mistake. Maybe that will be clarified when the errata for the Advanced Player's Guide is released.